# Add Images to iMessages style chat web page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on an iMessages style chat web page based on this [code sample](https://codepen.io/samuelkraft/details/Farhl).

I've got this working and now need to add inline images so they appear as part of the message thread. The base HTML/CSS is this:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  max-width: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

p:before,
p:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 20px;
}

.message-outgoing {
  color: white;
  background: #0B93F6;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.message-outgoing:before {
  right: -7px;
  border-right: 20px solid #0B93F6;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
}

.message-outgoing:after {
  right: -56px;
  width: 26px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}

.message-incoming {
  background: #E5E5EA;
  color: black;
}

.message-incoming:before {
  left: -7px;
  border-left: 20px solid #E5E5EA;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
}

.message-incoming:after {
  left: 4px;
  width: 26px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}
```

```html
<p class="message-outgoing">Hi - here's out breakfast bowl. Let me know what you think?</p>
<img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103803770/750/422/image.jpg">
<p class="message-incoming">Looks yummy!</p>

<p class="message-outgoing">Glad you like it - look forward to seeing you for breakfast soon.</p>
```

I've added an image which is display but I need to have 2 classes for images received and images sent, similar to the message-outgoing and message-incoming. I also need the images to not expand to the full width of the page but rather share the same max width as the message-outgoing and message-incoming do.

Can't work out what CSS to use here to have the 2 image classes for outgoing and incoming and set the max width of these as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a new class for img message, as a non-iPhone user I don't know if images have the little 'bubble speech' thing on the bottom but if they do this will be harder since it will involve background clipping over an SVG that fit the message bubble shape.
Here is something you can do to just add some images.

You can remove the background-image from the `img-msg` class and just create some class for each image you want to add like `name-img` with a certain background-image URL etc...

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: normal;
  max-width: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  max-width: 255px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position:relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
  border-radius:25px;
}

p:before, p:after {
    content:"";
        position:absolute;
    bottom:-2px;
    height:20px;
  }

.from-me {
    color:white; 
    background:#0B93F6;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.from-me:before {
        right:-7px;
        border-right:20px solid #0B93F6;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
                transform:translate(0, -2px);
    }

.from-me:after {
        right:-56px;
        width:26px;
        background:white;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
                transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
    }
.from-them {
    background:#E5E5EA;
    color:black;
}
.from-them:before {
        left:-7px;
        border-left:20px solid #E5E5EA;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
                transform:translate(0, -2px);
    }
.from-them:after {
        left:4px;
        width:26px;
        background:white;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
                transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
    }
 .img-msg {
   background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/375x812'); 
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   min-height: 400px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   //background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center;
}
 .img-msg:before {
   display: none !important
}
.iphone-img{

   background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597740985671-2a8a3b80502e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80') !important; 

}
```

```html
<p class="from-me">Hey there! What's up</p>
<p class="from-them">Checking out iOS7 you know..</p>
<p class="from-me">Check this out</p>
<p class="from-me img-msg"></p>
<p class="from-them">I got the same picture !</p>
<p class="from-them img-msg"></p>
<p class="from-them">Now, check this one !</p>
<p class="from-them img-msg iphone-img"></p>
```